# Is it right to manually add an extension to the configuration file?

Tags: magento2, module, magento-community

While learning to build Magento 2 extensions, I have come across several tutorials (blogs, books and videos) teaching me different things. When it comes to registering a new extension, some tutorials ask me to manually add my extension to the `app/etc/config.php` file, while others say it is out of place to manually edit the `app/etc/config.php`.

Is it right to manually add an extension to the configuration (`app/etc/config.php`) file?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It is not ideal process to Add an extension directly from `app/etc/config.php`.

In other to add an extension you have to run

`php bin/magento module:enable {Vendorname}_{ModuleName}`

After running this command a record inserted at config.php `  like

> {Vendorname}_{ModuleName} => 1

then you have to run  setup upgrade command

`php bin/magento setup:upgrade`

Note that running, of Module disable command makes `

> {Vendorname}_{ModuleName} => 0`

`php bin/magento module:disable {Vendorname}_{ModuleName}`